Vault Spring library Authentication Error Listener is not getting executed upon token renewal failure
Note the below code and the method sessionManager() where I am adding listener "VaultEventListener" to the session. VaultEventListener class code also provided below.
My requirement is that whenever there is error in call to renew the existing token, the vault event listener to be invoked whenever there is token renew error so that I can retry with multiple attampts.
class SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig extends AbstractVaultConfiguration {

    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig.class);
     
    @Override
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {

        try {
            GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
            String account = null;
            if (credential instanceof ServiceAccountCredentials) {
                account = ((ServiceAccountCredentials) credential).getAccount();
            } else if (credential instanceof ComputeEngineCredentials) {
                account = ((ComputeEngineCredentials) credential).getAccount();
            } else {
                logger.fatal(
                        "Unable to get service account email, Application default GoogleCredentials must be instance of ServiceAccountCredentials or ComputeEngineCredentials");
                return null;
            }
            logger.info("Application running with service account : {}", account);
            GcpIamCredentialsAuthenticationOptions options = GcpIamCredentialsAuthenticationOptions.builder()
                    .role(SntlVaultConfig.getGcpVaultLoginRole()).credentials(credential).serviceAccountId(account)
                    .build();
            GcpIamCredentialsAuthentication authN = new GcpIamCredentialsAuthentication(options, this.restOperations());
            return authN;
        } catch (IOException | SntlCloudEnvException e) {
            logger.fatal( "An exception occurred in setting up GCP IAM authentication for Vault.", e);;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        VaultEndpoint endPoint = new VaultEndpoint();
        try {
            endPoint.setHost(SntlVaultConfig.getVaultAddr());
            endPoint.setPort(SntlVaultConfig.getVaultPort());
            endPoint.setScheme(SntlVaultConfig.getVaultEndPointScheme());
            return endPoint;
        } catch (SntlCloudEnvException e) {
            logger.fatal( "SntlCloudEnvException occurred .", e);
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ClientOptions clientOptions() {
        try {
            return new ClientOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(SntlVaultConfig.getVaultConnectionTimeout()), Duration.ofSeconds(SntlVaultConfig.getVaultReadTimeout()));
        } catch (SntlCloudEnvException e) {
            logger.fatal( "SntlCloudEnvException occurred .", e);
            return null;
        }

    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SessionManager sessionManager() {
        
        boolean retryEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(SntlVaultConfig.isRetryTokenRenewal);
        int REFRESH_PERIOD_BEFORE_EXPIRY = Integer.parseInt(SntlVaultConfig.refreshBeforeExpiryDuration); //120; // Overrides default which is 5 seconds
 
        ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication = clientAuthentication();
        Assert.notNull(clientAuthentication, "ClientAuthentication must not be null");
       
       
        LifecycleAwareSessionManagerSupport.FixedTimeoutRefreshTrigger refreshTrigger = new LifecycleAwareSessionManagerSupport.FixedTimeoutRefreshTrigger(
                REFRESH_PERIOD_BEFORE_EXPIRY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        LifecycleAwareSessionManager lifecycleAwareSessionManager =  new LifecycleAwareSessionManager(clientAuthentication, getVaultThreadPoolTaskScheduler(), restOperations(), refreshTrigger);
        lifecycleAwareSessionManager.setLeaseStrategy(LeaseStrategy.retainOnError()); //To-validate
    
        VaultEventListener vaultEventListener = new VaultEventListener();
        lifecycleAwareSessionManager.addErrorListener(vaultEventListener);
        return lifecycleAwareSessionManager;
    }



public class VaultEventListener implements AuthenticationErrorListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VaultEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(AuthenticationErrorEvent event) {
        
        logger.info("AuthenticationErrorListener Error Source: {}", event.getSource());
        logger.info("AuthenticationErrorListener Exception: {}", event.getException());

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(SntlVaultConfig.isRetryTokenRenewal)) {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = SntlCloudEnvContext.getContext();

            SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig sntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig = context.getBean(SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig.class);
            sntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig.refreshToken();
        }
        
    }
}



public class VaultEventListener implements AuthenticationErrorListener {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VaultEventListener.class);

private final SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig vaultConfig;

public VaultEventListener(SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig vaultConfig) {
    this.vaultConfig = vaultConfig;
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(AuthenticationErrorEvent event) {
    logger.info("AuthenticationErrorListener Error Source: {}", event.getSource());
    logger.info("AuthenticationErrorListener Exception: {}", event.getException());

    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(SntlVaultConfig.isRetryTokenRenewal)) {
        int maxRetryAttempts = 3; // Define the maximum number of retry attempts
        for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= maxRetryAttempts; attempt++) {
            logger.info("Attempting token renewal retry, attempt: {}", attempt);
            try {
                vaultConfig.refreshToken(); // Assuming refreshToken() retries internally on error
                break; // Exit loop if renewal succeeds
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Token renewal retry failed, attempt: {}", attempt, e);
                // Log the error and retry
            }
        }
    }
}

}
VaultEventListener class, the onAuthenticationError method implements a simple retry mechanism for token renewal. It retries the refreshToken method up to a maximum number of attempts (maxRetryAttempts). If the renewal succeeds, it breaks out of the retry loop; otherwise, it continues retrying until reaching the maximum attempts.
You'll need to modify the sessionManager method in your SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig class to pass an instance of SntlVaultGcpIamAuthConfig to the VaultEventListener constructor:
VaultEventListener vaultEventListener = new VaultEventListener(this);
lifecycleAwareSessionManager.addErrorListener(vaultEventListener);
